# PHP - Se não existir conteúdo na linha não exiba

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver (não entendo muito de php) que acho ser simples.

Estou puxando um lista de produtos de um banco de dados, porém alguns produtos não tem imagem e eu gostaria que na hora do Loop ele não carregue os que tem alguma linha vazia.

Por exemplo: Caso não tenha nada na linha "imgmarca" ele não ecibe este produto na tela.

Ou melhor se em  não tiver nada não exibe o produto.

Segue código.

```
<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM techloja ORDER  BY RAND(), id DESC LIMIT 12");
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
if($total > 0) {
do {
?>          

<div class="produto_interna"  title="<?=$linha['nome']?>" >
        <a href="<?=$linha['link']?>">
        <div class="nome"><p><?=$linha['nomepeq']?> </p></div>

        <div class="foto">
        <div  class="foto_img"><p><img src="<?=$linha['img']?>"  title="<?=$linha['nome']?>" alt="<?=$linha['nome']?>" /></p></div>

        <div class="loja"><p><img src="<?=$linha['imgmarca']?>" height="30px" /> <span style="float:right; font-size:1.5em; font-weight:bold; color:#BC0003; margin-top:5px;">R$ <?=$linha['valor']?></span></p></div>
        <div class="comprar"><img src="images/comprar_bt.jpg"/></div>
        </div>


        </a>
  </div>


 <?php
    }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Adiciona um `if (!empty($linha)) {` depois do teu `do {` e assim ele só entra aí se a variavel $linha tiver conteudo

Comment: Não é uma boa prática utilizar `do { } while` da forma como usou.
Mesmo que só exista 1 único resultado, esse segundo `fetch` será executado.

Comment: Trocar esse do{}while por apenas o while. Assim você não precisa fazer essa checagem fora do laço, como está fazendo na terceira linha, e melhora a legibilidade do codigo.

Comment: @MarcosRegis era cool ensinares como ele deveria ter feito também ;) -- juntanto ao que o Marcos disse, era preferivel que usasses um `forEach($linhas as $linha)` mas aí terás que mudar a estrutura do código.

Comment: Então esse jeito que fiz é o único que "sei" mas adicionando o if (!empty($linha))  ele continua exibindo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso direto na `query`

```
SELECT * FROM techloja WHERE img IS NOT NULL ORDER  BY RAND(), id DESC LIMIT 12
```

Caso você salve o campo em branco em vez de NULL

```
SELECT * FROM techloja WHERE img != "" ORDER  BY RAND(), id DESC LIMIT 12
```

Ou pelo PHP usando a função [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use este código caso apenas não queira exibir a imagem quando o campo estiver vazio.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM techloja ORDER  BY RAND(), id DESC LIMIT 12";
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados) ) {?>          

<div class="produto_interna"  title="<?php echo $linha['nome']?>" >
        <a href="<?php echo $linha['link']?>">
        <div class="nome"><p><?php echo $linha['nomepeq']?> </p></div>
<?php
if (trim($linha['imgmarca']) != "") { ?>
        <div class="foto">
        <div  class="foto_img"><p><img src="<?php echo $linha['img']?>"  title="<?php echo $linha['nome']?>" alt="<?php echo $linha['nome']?>" /></p></div>

        <div class="loja"><p><img src="<?php echo $linha['imgmarca']?>" height="30px" /> <span style="float:right; font-size:1.5em; font-weight:bold; color:#BC0003; margin-top:5px;">R$ <?php echo $linha['valor']?></span></p></div>
        <div class="comprar"><img src="images/comprar_bt.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
        </a>
  </div>
 <?php    } // fim while 
 ?>
```

para evitar exibir o produto todo, use a dica do @Jeferson

Comment: Uma coisa que percebi agora é que seu SQL tem um `ORDER BY RAND(), id DESC` Escolhe apenas um dos dois pois, um anula o outro.

Comment: Havia esquecido de apagar isso do código...
Então esse código que passou deu certo, porém fica o espaço vazio onde ficaria o produto que não foi exibido.

Comment: Eu uso uma imagem de "SEM FOTO" para exibir um produto sem a foto.
Caso queira ocultar a linha inteira, use o SQL `SELECT * FROM techloja WHERE imgmarca IS NOT NULL AND imgmarca != "" ORDER  BY id DESC LIMIT 12`